# Spring Bean Name with package detail only

Tags: spring

I need to create bean with id or name with class name with it's package.

e.g

```
<bean class="org.chameleon.commons.context.resolver.impl.UserContextResolver" scope="prototype" 
/>
```

and I want it to be like this

```
org.chameleon.commons.context.resolver.impl.UserContextResolver
```

but it shows me like this.

```
org.chameleon.commons.context.resolver.impl.UserContextResolver@if
```

What to do to get bean as my required name.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an "id" or a "name" attribute to the bean definition, e.g.

```
<bean id="org.chameleon.commons.context.resolver.impl.UserContextResolver" class="org.chameleon.commons.context.resolver.impl.UserContextResolver" scope="prototype" />
```

As stated in Spring reference doc 5.3.1 Naming beans[1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beanname)

> In XML-based configuration metadata, **you use the id and/or name attributes to specify the bean identifier(s). The id attribute allows you to specify exactly one id. Conventionally these names are alphanumeric (myBean, fooService, etc.), but may contain special characters as well**. If you want to introduce other aliases to the bean, you can also specify them in the name attribute, separated by a comma (,), semicolon (;), or white space. **As a historical note, in versions prior to Spring 3.1, the id attribute was defined as an xsd:ID type, which constrained possible characters**. As of 3.1, it is defined as an xsd:string type. Note that bean id uniqueness is still enforced by the container, though no longer by XML parsers.
>   You are not required to supply a name or id for a bean. If no name or id is supplied explicitly, the container generates a unique name for that bean. However, if you want to refer to that bean by name, through the use of the ref element or Service Locator style lookup, you must provide a name.